# How to trigger error of __verify_pcpu_ptr?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
/*
 * __verify_pcpu_ptr() verifies @ptr is a percpu pointer without evaluating
 * @ptr and is invoked once before a percpu area is accessed by all
 * accessors and operations.  This is performed in the generic part of
 * percpu and arch overrides don't need to worry about it; however, if an
 * arch wants to implement an arch-specific percpu accessor or operation,
 * it may use __verify_pcpu_ptr() to verify the parameters.
 *
 * + 0 is required in order to convert the pointer type from a
 * potential array type to a pointer to a single item of the array.
 */
#define __verify_pcpu_ptr(ptr)                      \
do {                                    \
    const void __percpu *__vpp_verify = (typeof((ptr) + 0))NULL;    \
    (void)__vpp_verify;                     \
} while (0)
```

The comment states that the macro function can verify if `ptr` is a percpu pointer. However, when I tried the following code, I didn't get any warning or error.

```
void func(void)
{
    int localvar = 10;
    __verify_pcpu_ptr(&localvar);
}

int main(void)
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Does the function really work? And how?

Comment: The macro `__verify_pcpu_ptr` is for **compile-time** type checks only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831335/verify-pcpu-ptr-function-in-linux-kernel-what-does-it-do. GCC doesn't differentiate between `__percpu` pointer and "normal" pointer. But sparse will emit a warning when cast "pointer to int" to "pointer to const void but in __percpu address space". See comments about such "address space" in the Linux kernel code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/compiler_types.h#L18